# Find Main in Assembly

Tags: c++, debugging, assembly, reverse-engineering

I have simple C++ programm:

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;  
void main()  
{  
    cout << "Hello, world, from Visual C++!" << endl;  
}
```

Compiled with following command: `cl /EHsc hello.cpp`

I want to start debugging of executable, How can I find this main function's corresponding assembly code in the debugger? (I'm using x64dbg)

Entry point is not same as Main function.
I found main function and it is somewhere not near with Entry Point, I had strings and I found this easily.

Is there any way or rule or best practise how to guess where is main's corresponding assmebly code?

**EDIT:**

I have source code, but I just learning RE.

Comment: Just being pedantic: it's `int main(int argc, char** argv)` or `int main()`, not `void main()`.

Comment: Some executables contain code that initializes the environment, *then calls `main`*.  If your debugger can't find the `main`, then you need to compiler **all** files in debug mode (so that the executable contains symbol information).

Comment: If you have the source code, tell your compiler (or linker) to generate a `map` file.  The map file will contain symbols and their addresses.  Search the map file for `main`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: The OP is obviously using Microsoft's compiler/linker, which doesn't (by default) embed symbol information. It generates program database files (PDBs). This is not related to compiling in *debug mode* (which doesn't even exist).

Comment: If you are learning RE, and you expect the "target" being stripped of debug info and optimized, then that's it, what you have. Entry point, and guess game. If the target was at least built by some common compiler + common entry initializer used, you can probably compare it to the set of known inits you will collect, so you will quickly find the final `call main` instruction. (I think (not sure), that actually the entry code is out of optimization process, so it will be fixed for particular version of compiler).

Comment: @JonnyHenly The implementation may allow `void main()` as an extension.

Comment: @j-doe I think this question is better suited on http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the entry point is usually not the `main` defined in your executable, this is merely because it is quite common for compilers to to wrap `main` with some initialization code.

In most cases the initialization code is quite similar and has one of few versions per compiler. Most of those functions have an [IDA FLIRT signature](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/tech/flirt/in_depth.shtml), and opening the binary with IDA will define an `WinMain`, `main`, etc function for you automatically. You can also use free (trial) versions of IDA for that.

If that's not the case, it's pretty straight forward to get from the entrypoint to the `main`, by following the few calls inside the entrypoint function one level deep. the `main` call is usually near the end of the entrypoint function.

Here's an example, `main` function is selected near the bottom (Note this is a unix executable compiled for windows using mingw, so this is somewhat different from most native win32 executables).

[image: mingw32 executable entry point]

Answer (score 2):

if you debugging own code - the best way to stop somewhere under debugger - use next code

`if (IsDebuggerPresent()) __debugbreak();`

so you can insert it at begin of your `main` or any other places.

if you debugging not own binary code - binary can at all not containing `c/c++` `CRT` code - so question became senseless. however if `CRT` code exist, despite many different implementations - all use common patterns and after some practice - possible found where `CRT` code call `main`.

in case standard windows binaries, for which exist `pdb` files - this is not a problem at all

Answer (score 1):

*Generally, you can't.*

When you compile a program, you get a binary and (optionally) debugging symbols.

If you have the debugging symbols, let IDA or your debugger load them, and then you should be able to symbolically evaluate `main` to the address of the function (e.g in IDA, just press `g` and write `main` and you'll be there. In WinDbg or gdb you can type `b main`)

However, the more common case would be to find the `main` function on a binary for which you do not posses the debugging symbols. In this case, you don't know where the `main` function is, nor if it is even there. The binary may not use the common `libc` practice of an entry point doing initialization and then calling `main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])`.

But because you're an intelligent human, I'd recommended reading the `libc` implementation for the compiler/platform you think you're working with, and follow the logic from the platform-defined entry point until you see the `call main` instruction.

(Please note that .NET binaries and other types of binaries may behave completely differently.)